# Prevent all access/IP logging in Apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, ip, logging

Is it possible to configure Apache2 to prevent logging any IP addresses or other information from user web requests, essentially making all users of a site anonymous?

Answer (score 5):

You can write your custom logs as follow:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
CustomLog logs/access_log common
```

the `%h` is the client ip address, just omit it:

```
LogFormat "%l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
CustomLog logs/access_log common
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to run your logs through any standard stats processing tool, you'll want to put something else in place of the %h there, just to keep the log parsing happy. For example, you could do:

```
LogFormat "1.1.1.1 %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
```

or similar, and that would log something there, but not the actual visitor's IP address.